# Store media files(Images,Audio, Video) in HDFS and query using Spark/Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have media files (Images,Audio, Video) as my input. I want to store this into HDFS and retrieve using Spark or Python queries. How it is possible ???

Comment: Did you find the way to figure it out? I am looking for same